# WinUI HyperlinkButton is not displayed underlined

Tags: xaml, user-interface, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I am using the WinUI technology.

I would like to display a `HyperlinkButton` in my XAML.

The problem is that the `HyperlinkButton` is not displayed underlined.
But according to this documentation this should be the case / the default behavior: [MSDN - HyperlinkButton Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.hyperlinkbutton?view=winui-3.0#remarks)

Here is what I have:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Example" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" />
```

Neither I have any style that would affect how the button is displayed nor did I change a template.

What am I missing?
Thank you.

**UPDATE**

The problem exists in version 1.0.1 (march 2022) of Windows App SDK as well as in version  1.0.0 (november 2021), see [windows-app-sdk/downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads)

Comment: I got the result same as you. And I'm trying to consult.

Answer (score 1):

The template of the `HyperlinkButton` has changed in [later versions of the Windows App SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/2291) (1.0.0+) but apparently the documentation hasn't been updated.

You should still be able to use a `Hyperlink` element to get an underlined link though:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink_Click">Example</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a visual studio project that still targets Windows App SDK version 1.0.0 and the behavior is the same, i.e. the link is not displayed underlined. So I presume that new version 1.0.1 has nothing to do with this? However the example you provided with the Hyperlink inside a TextBlock works, the link is displayed underlined. Should we remove the part of the answer that mentions the new version of the Windows App SDK? I will update my question respectivly (the problem exists in 1.0.0 and 1.0.1).

Comment: I guess it was modified prior to 1.0.1 being released then. I edited the answer slightly. Anyway, the templates has changed and the text of a `HyperlinkButton` is no longer underlined by default.

Answer (score 1):

[HyperlinkButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.hyperlinkbutton?view=winui-3.0#remarks) **missing underlined text** is almost confirmed a bug.
As a workaround to add underline on the button text string, you can try the following way to display something with `TextDecorations` property as "Underline".

```
        <HyperlinkButton Click="HyperlinkButton_Click">
            <TextBlock Text="www.microsoft.com" TextDecorations="Underline" />
        </HyperlinkButton>
```

**Edit**:
Finally, according to [the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7000),

> The documentation needs updating to reflect the updated design for
> HyperlinkButton first introduced in WinUI 2.6, see the WinUI [Figma
> toolkit](https://www.figma.com/community/file/989931624019688277) for more info.